# backbone collection search url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new with backbone and need to create a search page. To do this i have a collection with an event handler, when the user click on the search button this event is triggered.

This is the handler function for this event:

```
on_request_search_phone_call:function(args) {
    //GET DATES TO SEND
    var start_date = args[0].toString('MM-dd-yyyyHH:mm:ss');
    var end_date    = args[1].toString('MM-dd-yyyyHH:mm:ss');

    //HERE IS WHERE URL SHOULD BE CHANGED TO SEND START DATE AND END DATE
}
```

I would like to know the best way to change the url and fetch the data with those params.

Comment: Everything depends in how the server side is expecting the search request.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone.js comes with a (url) [router](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router), using it you can do something like the following

`myRouter.navigate("search/" + start_date + '/' + end_date , {trigger: true});`

You will of course need to make sure your routes and router are set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch as follow:

```
     var start_date = DATE1,
         end_date = DATE2
     collection.fetch({ reset : true,
              data  : {
                start_date : start_date,
                end_date   : end_date
              }
});
```

in GET request to server

```
http://your.domain/search/?start_date=DATE1?end_date=DATE2
```

and on the server side you can reach them.